# How do I render a KaTex equation in Angular? I've tried using ng-katex but it didn't work as expected

Tags: angular, katex

I'm new to Katex/Latex and I've tried different approaches, but I couldn't get the output right. I've tried using katex.org's autorender function and below delimiter but line break and symbols are not correctly rendered.

`{ left: '$$', right: '$$', display: true }, { left: '$', right: '$', display: true }`

The output I want: https://prnt.sc/yxfanc
Current output: https://prnt.sc/yxfdzg

I can't modify the string because the string is coming from db.

`$$0.01$$ mol of $$AgNO_3$$ is added to $$1$$ L of&#160;a solution which is $$0.1\\ M$$ $$Na_2CrO_4$$ and $$0.005\\ M$$ in $$NaIO_3$$. Calculate&#160; $$[Ag^{\\oplus}],[IO_3^{\\circleddash}]$$ and $$[CrO_4^{2-}]$$.&#160;<div>$$K_{sp}\\, Ag_2CrO_4$$ and $$AgIO_3$$ are $$10^{-8}$$ and $$10^{-13}$$ respectively.</div>`

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, welcome to LaTeX! The first moments are complicated, but once you understand the logic, everything will be fine.

In your example, there is a confusion between the `\` and the `\\`. In the first case, it indicates that one command follows the backslash, in the other it is a line break (we can see the second backslash of `\\` as being the line break command).
So we would have `$$IO_3^{\circleddash}$$` and not `$$IO_3^{\circleddash}$$`.

In addition, there are also libraries that allow you to write the units of the international system in their correct form. Indeed in the document it is sometimes written "mol" and "M" elsewhere.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{SIunits}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$0.01 \mole$ of $AgNO_3$ is added to $1 \liter$  of a solution which is $0.1 \mole$ 
in $Na_2CrO_4$ and $0.005 \mole$ in $NaIO_3$.
\\
Calculate $[Ag^{\oplus}],[IO_3^{\ominus}]$ and $[CrO_4^{2-}]$. 
\\
$K_{sp} Ag_2CrO_4$ and $AgIO_3$ are $10^{-8}$ and $10^{-13}$ respectively.
\end{document}
```